# Get the key with the maximum nested key in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so:

```
my_dictionary = {
      'key1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 10}, 
      'key2': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 11}, 
      'key3': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 12}
}
```

How can I compare the 'c' subkeys of this dictionary, find the greatest one, and return the corresponding parent key of that dictionary (in this case I want to output `'key3'` as it's `'c'` key is highest). Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) optionally accepts a callable argument for modifying the comparison:

```
>>> d
{'key1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 10},
 'key2': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 11},
 'key3': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 12}}
>>> max(d, key=lambda v: d[v]['c'])
'key3'
```

Comment: what to do if c has NaN values?